# Integer and Space in regex

Tags: regex

I am trying to match strings which contains integer and space. Can someone help me out? The string is 3 characters in length. In the example below i have used the character 'b' to indicate blank-space character.

valid strings are,

1bb

12b

123

b12

bb1

Invalid String is,

bbb

Comment: Then language you are describing is not regular!

Comment: you actually mean that `123`, `111`, `777`, or `bb8` are all accepted patterns, right? (any digit is fine)

Answer (score 0):

use this regex `(?=.*?\d)(?=.*? ).+`

Answer (score 0):

If you know the string is 3 characters already, you can use

```
/^ {0,2}\d+ {0,2}$/
```

or even a simpler

```
/^ *\d+ *$/
```

This is optional space in front, plus a mandatory digit (or more), and optional space at the end.

An assumption is that `b2b` is also considered acceptable.  If not, then

```
/^(\d+ *)|( *\d+)$/
```

can be used.